# Two double type arrays into one, C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a console app with two double type arrays, but i have a problem.
How can i add two arrays into one, but without repeating same number (i have same number in two arrays)?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Union` from Linq:

```
double[] a = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
double[] b = new double[] { 3, 4, 5, 6 };

double[] arr = a.Union(b).ToArray();
```

Variable `arr` will now contain `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`.